# Postgresql - implementation of LRU cache - eviction of items

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I am implementing a LRU cache in Postgres.

I have a list of items. Each item has a priority and a weight. The lower the priority, the earlier is must be evicted from the cache. Let's take following items:

```
priority | weight
-----------------
1          2
2          3
3          3
4          1
5          2
```

Now, I want to make room for a new item to be added. The weight of this new item is `6`, so items of priority `1`, `2` and `3` (the first three rows) must be removed to make place for this new item.

I am trying to come up with a query returns these row. Currently, I have the following solution:

```
with
item (priority, weight) as (
    select 1, 2 union all
    select 2, 3 union all
    select 3, 3 union all
    select 4, 1 union all
    select 5, 2
),
item_weighted (priority, cumulative_weight) as (
    select  priority, sum(weight) over (order by priority)
    from    item
)
select  priority
from    item_weighted
where   priority <= (select priority from item_weighted where cumulative_weight >= 6 order by priority limit 1);
```

Explanation:

- In CTE `item_weighted` I calculate the cumulative weight of each item.
- In the query itself, I select all items where the priority is lower or greater than the priority of the item where where the cumulative weight becomes greater than `6`.

So, this works. But, I am not really really happy with this solution. First selecting a single row, and then selecting all rows before that row, seems odd to me.

I believe that there are more elegant approaches possible. Can this be improved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the `lag` window function:

```
SELECT priority
FROM (SELECT priority,
             lag(cumulative_weight, 1, BIGINT '0')
                OVER (ORDER BY cumulative_weight) lagging_weightsum
      FROM (SELECT priority,
                   sum(weight)
                      OVER (ORDER BY priority) cumulative_weight
            FROM item
           ) cumulated
     ) lagging
WHERE lagging_weightsum < 6;
```

I don't know if that is more elegant, but it does not scan the table twice.

What if you have the same priority twice? Shouldn't the table have a primary key?

Comment: I will try with the `lag` window function, that is new for me! About your question: the priority is the primary key here, so the order is always guaranteed (if that was your concern?).

Comment: I see. I was confused because that is an unusual meaning of "priority"; it is more like "position in line".

Comment: Good point! It is indeed a unique position in the queue. I might rename it in my code, as it is indeed not clear ;). (I will accept your answer later today, when I have time to play with the `lag` window function.)

Comment: I am not really sure that the query works. If I set the threshold to `5` instead of `6`, the first three items are still returned. I expect the first two items to be returned, as their weight sum is 5. Any idea?

Comment: There was a bug. It should be `< 6` rather than `<= 6`.